# Rings and Categories of Modules by Anderson and Fuller: Corollary $7.4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am reading the book *Rings and Categories of Modules* by Anderson and Fuller. I don't understand corollary $7.4$ of that book. Can anyone explain that corollary to me?

Thank for any insight.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which corollary? This page has two... Also, any narrowing of your question would be helpful. If you already understand some part we would prefer not to make you read through reexplanation.

Comment: It's corollary $7.4$

Comment: Dear chuyenvien94 : "Explain this 6 part equivalence" is not a very good question for this community. Which implication (or two or three) do you want to ask about?

Comment: Let me put it another way: you tried to do one of these implications and got stuck. Where?